# Paperclip gem "not a git repository"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, rubygems, paperclip

when I run bundle install after adding

```
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

to my Gemfile, I get the following error:

> S-406c8f0a8159:etsydemo vivian.zhang$ bundle install
>   Updating git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
>   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
>   Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*" due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` in directory /Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69 has failed.
>   If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69'
>   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
>   Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*" due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` in directory /Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69 has failed.
>   If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69'
>   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
>   Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags
>   'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` in
>   directory
>   /Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69
>   has failed.
>   If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
>   '/Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69'

I've searched around and it seems this means that the git repository doesn't exist. However, I copied and pasted directly from the documentation, so I'm not sure what to do. The same thing happens when I place this into my Gemfile as well:

```
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'
```

Here's my entire Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you're adding the naked repo to your Gemfile & not using the version number, to download from Rubygems like normal?

Comment: It's a known error in the paperclip gem, including the version number causes an error which is known to be solved by adding the naked repo. Ironically, that causes this error instead...

Answer (score 0):

Not with paperclip gem, but I have run into a similar problem with the gem line using `github:` option and bundler 1.17.2.

It showed the message very similar to what you pasted:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git 
Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags 
    'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git' "refs/heads/:refs/heads/" 
    due to error (2/3): 
Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: 
    command git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*" 
in directory 
    /Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69 
has failed. 

If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory 
'/Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69'
```

Here is how I solved the problem:

```sh
# Create missing `refs` directory in each bundler's git-repo cache:
cd /Users/vivian.zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git
bash -xc 'for i in *; do mkdir -p $i/refs/{heads,tags}; done'
```

I don't know why the bundler created git-repo caches which didn't contain `refs` directory. Anyway, creating `refs` directory seems to be a remedy for the problem.